# populating due date in html from a transaction date by using java script

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have an html java script form, with that I am trying to populate the due date of a transaction based on the input transaction date. In my script i have to input the transaction date as 2014-10-11 (YYYY-MM-DD), then i am getting the correct output in the format 20-Nov-2014. 
Is there any option to input the date in DD-MM-YYYY format and the populate output also in the same DD-MM-YYYY format? I am attaching my script. Please help.

html / Java script

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function txnfn(){
                //alert(document.getElementById("txnType").value);
                //alert(document.getElementById("txnType").value);
                if(document.getElementById("txnType").value=='ccpurch'){
                    document.getElementById("duedtdiv").style.display="block";
                    document.getElementById("duedt").value = dat.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("duedtdiv").style.display="none";
                }

            }

         function   txn40()
         {
          var dt = document.getElementById("txndt").value;
           var dat = new Date(dt);
                    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 40);
          document.getElementById("duedt").value = dat.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
         }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            Transaction Type: <select name="txnType" id="txnType" onchange="txnfn();">
            <option value="ccpurch">Purchase</option>
            <option value="ccrefund">Refund</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        Transaction date:<input id ="txndt" type="date" name ="purch_date" onblur = "txn40();"/>
        <br/><br/>
                <div id="duedtdiv">
        Due date:<input id ="duedt" type="date" name ="due_date" readonly/>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use moment.js to Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in javascript

```
//date time right now 
moment();
//formate it to mm-dd-yyyy
moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY");
//Due date after adding 40 days in DD-MM-YYYY format
moment().add(40, 'days').format("MM-DD-YYYY");
```

[Moment.js website](http://momentjs.com/)

[Jsfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/naveedcs/0L4qsq43/)

add a reference to moment.js on your webpage and modify your function like this

```
function   txn40()
     {
      var dt = document.getElementById("txndt").value;          
      document.getElementById("duedt").value = moment(dt).add(40,'days').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. But I am very sorry, i am trying to modify my code with the input provided by you. I am not able to modify it. I am just a beginner, so i have not that much idea about the java script. I request you to , if you don't mind, could you please help me for correcting my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. the script is working perfectly now. Once again thank you for your valuable time.